# Interval is starting twice after cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an interval and send request. It will start with click and stop with click. Starting and stopping working great. But after stopping the interval when you pressed the button again to start it, interval starts twice. After stopping it and start it again, it starts 3 interval.

Here is my code:

```
var running=0
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '.html' );
var pathArray = pathArray.reverse();
var pathArray = pathArray .join('');
var pathArray= pathArray .split('/');
var bidnum=pathArray[3];
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('body').append("<div id=\"cdjs\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 30px; background-color: gray; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px; left: 30px;\">Click to start</div>");
        $('#cdjs').click(letswin); 

    });

    function checkandbid(){
            if(running==1){
                $.get("http://www.bigibid.com/LiveResponder/LR.bid?_as="+bidnum, function(data){
                    Marray = data.split("'te':'")
                    time = Marray[1].split("'")
                    time = time[0]
                    $('#cdjs').html(time);
                    if(time < 2 && able==1){
                            able=0;
                            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibBid').click();
                    }else{
                        able=1;
                    }
                });
            }
    }

        function letswin(){
            if(running==1){
                    running=0
                    clearInterval(IntRun);
                    delete IntRun;
                    $('#cdjs').html('Click to start'); 
            }else if(running==0){
                running++
                delete IntRun;
                clearInterval(IntRun);
                var IntRun = setInterval(checkandbid, 300);
                }

        }

    function bidders(){
    }
```

And here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKZcT/8/)

Answer (score 3):

Your `IntRun` variable is only scoped within the `letswin` function, and will be reset to an undefined value each time the function is invoked.

You need to move its declaration *outside* of that function, so that its value is remembered between invocations.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked nice. I will accept your answer in minutes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you know that, I know that, but the text I have is probably easier to grok ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `letswin` function declares a **local** variable called `IntRun`. It does not persist between calls to the function. You'll need to move it out to the containing scope for it to be maintained between calls.

Also note that you don't use `delete` on variables you declare with `var`. Only on object properties. (The purpose of the `delete` operator in JavaScript is to remove a property from an object.)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var running = false;
var checkandbidInterval;

function letswin(){
    if (checkandbidInterval) {
        clearInterval(checkandbidInterval);
    }

    if (running){
        running = false;

        $('#cdjs').html('Click to start');

    }
    else {
        running = true;

        checkandbidInterval = setInterval(checkandbid, 300);
    }

}
```

Note the variable changes as you had intRun as a local scope variable, not global scope.

Also, if you are checking a variable for 0 or 1, then just use a boolean instead (true or false).